# Best way to show explanatory content on top of the page - using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, bootstrap-4

https://i.postimg.cc/5NG7zT7t/arrow.jpg

**Please take a look at the picture in the link**
The yellow arrow has animation (I guess it's a css animation).
**Problem:**
I have a page and I need to show the user where to look (by using a yellow arrow for example) and I want the arrow to disappear after few seconds.
**Is there any JavaScript library that can make my life easier?**

I'm also using Bootstrap 4 and the framework is VueJS 2

Thank you

Comment: Probably you can find a library for this, though SO is not a correct place to search for a one. Also, what you need can be achieved with a couple of lines of JS and some CSS rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an HTML code:

```
<body onload="triggerMe()">
    .....
    .....
    <div id="arrow">
        Your arrow, this area will be set as absolute and its wrapper will be relative
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    triggerMe() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById("arrow").style.display = "none";
        }, 5000); // 5 seconds
    }
</script>
```

Comment: No need to get a library for this.